# Complex summation simplification

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

[image]

What I'm getting is 
$$\frac{( \sin (N+1)x - 2^N \sin x)}{(2^N(\sin x - 2))}$$

How do I simplify to the form they have given , please help.

[image]

I hope it's clear because I don't know Ajax still thats why I avoided putting the picture, please if any of you find pictures aren't appropriate , just give me some days to learn Ajax. 
After this ending point I just simplified what i got.
[image]

Comment: Assuming your $x$ is the same as $\theta$, your answer is wrong because it does not give $(\sin\theta)/2$ when $N=1$.  You'd better post your working and see if anyone can pick the error.

Comment: Why don't you show us how you got that result?

Comment: Yes my x is thetha, ok wait I'm sorry il show :)

Comment: Done :) read the description below the picture ;) thank you :)

Comment: I wrote it complete and clearly again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum _{n=1}^N \frac{\sin(\theta n)}{2^n}$$

First, let's rewrite it as an exponential ->

$$\sum _{n=1}^N i 2^{-n-1} e^{-i \theta  n}-i 2^{-n-1} e^{i \theta  n}$$

Sum->

$$ = \frac{i2^{-N-1}e^{-i\theta(N+1)}\left(2e^{i\theta}-e^{2i\theta}-2^{N+1}e^{i \theta(N+1)}+e^{2i\theta(N+1)}+2^{N+1}e^{2i\theta+i\theta(N+1)}-2e^{i\theta+2i\theta  (N+1)}\right)}{\left(-2+e^{i\theta}\right)\left(-1+2e^{i\theta}\right)}$$

Reduce ->

$$ = \frac{i 2^{-N-1} e^{-i \theta  N} \left(-e^{i \theta }-2^{N+1} e^{i \theta  N}-2 e^{2 i \theta  (N+1)}+2^{N+1} e^{i \theta  (N+2)}+e^{i (\theta +2 \theta  N)}+2\right)}{-\left(5 e^{i \theta }\right)+2 e^{2 i \theta }+2}$$

Expand, factor, and reduce ->

$$ = -\frac{2^{-N} \left(\sin  (\theta  N)-2 (\sin  (\theta  (N+1)))+2^{N+1} (\theta  \sin )\right)}{4 (\theta  \cos )-5} $$

Re-arrange ->

$$ = \frac{\sin  (\theta  N)-2 (\sin  (\theta  (N+1)))+2^{N+1} (\theta  \sin )}{2^N (4 (\theta  \cos )-5)}$$

Swap the signs ->

$$ = \frac{\sin  (\theta  N)+2 (\sin  (\theta  (N+1)))-2^{N+1} (\theta  \sin )}{2^N (5-4 (\theta  \cos ))}$$

Comment: Please can you explain how you got to the first step (line 2 of yours) . How did u get that long expression? Thank you.

Comment: Can you find my mistake please :D

Comment: Can you tell me how you got 2^-(n+1) ? :)

Comment: Updated, hopefully that clarifies things..  Also, I'm having trouble reading your hand-writing so it's not immediately obvious where you went wrong above..  Try working through it again, checking each step along the way.  You were so close!  I'm guessing it was an arithmetic error that flubbed you up.

Comment: Ok I will :D thank you :) but I don't understand how you got -n-1 for the power of 2.

Comment: Ah, ok. Just expanded that step further for you...

Comment: I understood :) I understood thank you a lot....sorry was troubling u :p I'm still in high school that's why takes some time to grasp it....